# Are all three grub entries after running Boot-Repair needed?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

After running `Boot-Repair` to fix things when dual booting windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04.3, multiple entries are left in the grub menu. Three come from

```
menuentry "Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 4659-4959
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" --users "" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 4659-4959
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}

menuentry "EFI/Lenovo/Boot/bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 4659-4959
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Lenovo/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

The second is recommended in the Boot-Repair documentation as the one to use
to boot Windows 8, but equally it seems the first option does the job fine too, and the last give access to settings. Do I really need all these, or can I simply comment them out in `25_custom`?

Similarly, given that the original boot entry for windows in `30_os-prober` is defunct, can I just comment it out?

What is the difference between each of these efi boot loaders anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The first two are probably duplicate files. I don't know about the third; it could be another duplicate or it could be something Lenovo-specific.

Background: The EFI spec says that each OS should install its boot loader in a subdirectory of the `EFI` directory on the ESP, as in `EFI/Microsoft` for Windows or `EFI/ubuntu` for Ubuntu. The `EFI/BOOT` directory is a special case: It holds a boot loader (`bootmgfw.efi`) that serves as a fallback in case all others fail. That's also the name that's used for boot loaders on removable media like USB flash drives. Thus, many OSes, including Windows, install two copies of their boot loaders -- once in the official directory and again as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. GRUB tends to pick these both up and present them as options, because they *can* be different boot loaders, even though they often are not.

This is complicated by Boot Repair. Old versions of this program, and new ones if you select a certain option in the Advanced menu, back up both the `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` and the `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` boot loaders (by renaming them with `bkp` placed at the start of the filename) and place copies of GRUB in their place. This is done to work around bugs in some EFIs. The problem is that this creates additional boot loader files, which can clutter menus and add to confusion when doing manual maintenance. Unless you need to use this backup-and-replace hack because of a broken EFI, I recommend that you *not* let Boot Repair make this change. Note, however, that this has not caused the duplication you've noted, although it has affected the filenames that GRUB has entered on its `chainloader` lines.

Personally, I'd remove the `EFI/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi` (or `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`) entry, since it could conceivably be changed to something else should some other tool decide to take over that spot. Hijacking the Windows boot loader is a little less likely -- although because of the EFI bug I've noted, at least two tools (Boot Repair and rEFInd's `mvrefind.sh` script) can do this, and others may do so in the future.

A tip: The `diff` command is your friend. Pass it two filenames and it will tell you if they're identical or not. No output indicates that the files are identical. You can use this to discover which `.efi` files on your system are identical to which other files.

Comment: In my ` EFI/BOOT directory is a special case: It holds a boot loader (bootmgfw.efi)` in my `EFI/BOOT` I seem to only see `bootx64.efi` (and its boot-repair backup), is this what you meant? (It would seem consistent with your later comment that "Windows, install two copies of their boot loaders -- once in the official directory and again as EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi" )

Comment: Using `diff` I see so far that `/boot/efi/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi ==/boot/efi/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi == /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi ==/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`

Comment: and also `/boot/efi/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi`

Comment: I understand your explanation of why `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` exists as a fallback option for win 8, but why does `bootx64.efi` also exist a second time as `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi`?

Comment: I haven't studied this in detail, but I think that Boot Repair installs a copy of GRUB as `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi`. I don't know why they do this; to the best of my knowledge, such a copy serves no purpose, since AFAIK no EFI or other boot loader treats that file as anything special.